# how to execute SQL with if condition in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

how to execute SQL with if condition in c#?

This is my query and went i execute this query i get an error saying "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."
I m using MS ACCESS as back end

```
     mycon.ConnectionString = ConnString;
            mycon.Open();

            string mySelectQuery = "IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Employee AS t1 WHERE t1.ssn ='"+textBox4.Text+"' "+
                                    "))begin UPDATE Employee  SET "+
                                    "fname ='"+textBox1.Text+"' ,"+
                                    "minit ='"+textBox2.Text+"' ," +
                                    "lname ='" + textBox3.Text+"', " +
                                    "ssn ='" +textBox4.Text+"', " + 
                                    "bdate ='" +textBox5.Text+"', " +
                                    "address ='" +textBox6.Text+"', " +
                                    "sex ='" +textBox7.Text+ "', " +
                                    "salary ='" +textBox8.Text+"', " +
                                    "superssn ='" +textBox9.Text+"', " +
                                    "dno ='" +comboBox2.Text+"'" +
                                   " WHERE ssn = '"+textBox4.Text+"' "+
                                    "end "+
                                    "else "+
                                   " begin "+
                                   " INSERT INTO employee  values ('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"','"+textBox8.Text+"','"+textBox9.Text+"','"+comboBox2.Text+"')"+
                                    " end";

            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, mycon);

           int Success=  myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This code has sql injection issues.  You should probably use a stored procedure to implement this logic.

Comment: Take @Hogan 's advice.  Put your logic in a stored procedure and make a call to it from your application code.

Comment: This is the worst possible way you can write database code.  Your server will be owned within hours.

Comment: can i write Sp in MS access ?

Comment: The ttittle is nice- this has NOTHING to do with .NET - if you dont know how to write valid SQL, say so. Don't blame the outer programming language.

Comment: @Arunachalam yes MS Access allows for SPs -- that's why I suggested it. eg http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=202116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support the `IF` statement. Nor `else` or `begin`. You'll have to do this in your C# code, such as performing your `"SELECT * FROM Employee AS t1 WHERE t1.ssn ='"+textBox4.Text + "'";` query first and then performing the next one if there are results.

Also, you should either use a parameterized queries or escape the values of you text boxes.

Comment: Technically you can get the same result as the IF statement via two statements (an update then an insert) and checking for nulls.  If someone asks I'll post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want to happen is `UPDATE` a record if it `Exists` in database, else `INSERT` a record.

You can't do this in one query, so prepare a query for a look-up in database if the record exists, then use the output (isExists or not) to `UPDATE` or `INSERT`